# Code::Blocks to XCode : importing a C++ with a GUI

Tags: c++, xcode, import, interface-builder, codeblocks

I currently have a project, written in C++, it uses multiple libraries, including an sqlite and a wxWidgets library, it has a Graphical User Interface, made with Interface Builder.

This project was made with Code::Blocks.

What I now want to do, is import this whole project into XCode to make an .app file. I know about linking and search paths and all that (learned how to do that with a Command Line Project), but other then that, I don't really know where to start. I have searched a lot of forums but it's driving me crazy.

Can anybody help me out with a step-by-step of some sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps taken

wx-config --cppflags
wx-config --libs

1. Opening a new xcode project (cocoa)
2. Pasting the code written (all the classes, and the interface built)
3. Organizing the header search paths (including the output of libs)
4. Organizing the linking
5. Organizing the GCC other flags (including the output of cppflags here)

after that it worked.